# Var won't update when changed

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the value of "June" with an input. By default, the value is `4` (line 12).  When I try to update it by input, the chart doesn't update.  I use the var (line 39).  What am I doing wrong?

I can give you the full code if needed but there's not much more to it for now, only cosmetic

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <input type="number" id="NbrPod" value="4"/>
  <script>
    var NbrPod = document.getElementById("NbrPod").value;
 </script>
  <div class="chart">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script>
    let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    // Global Options
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Helvetica';
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#777';

    let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
      type:'line', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
      data:{
        labels:['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        datasets:[{
          label:'Line 1',
          data:[
            61,
            18,
            15,
            10,
            11,
            NbrPod,
          ],
```

Comment: `there not Much more to it for now, only cosmetic` There in lies the problem. You must wire up a change event.

Comment: The value will always be `4`. Consider researching “input change event listener”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you assume that when the input updates the browser will re-evaluate your variable, but it won't. Script tags run once when the page is opened in the browser.

The only reason the browser will run JavaScript after the page is first opened is if you have assigned functions to "events" such as "click" or "scroll".

So you can updated your first script tag to attach an "event listener" to the input. With an input element you could listen for a "change" event or a "keyup" event, but in your case I would choose the "blur" event which happens after a user activated the input field and then left it by clicking outside it or pressing tab.

```
var NbrPod = document.getElementById("NbrPod") // remove .value
var NbrPodVal = NbrPod.value // declare var and set initial value
NbrPod.addEventListener("blur", function (event) {
  NbrPodVal = event.target.value
  // event is an object depicting the blur event
  // event.target is the HTML element the blur happened to
  // event.target.value is the new value of your input element
})
```

After this, whatever number is typed in the input field will be stored in the global variable NbrPodVal.

As a side note: it's conventional to start variable names only with _ or a lowercase letter; in JavaScript names that start with an uppercase letter are reserved for JavaScript classes.